# Insert into table (select from table) error while timestamp

Tags: sql-server, timestamp

I want to insert missing rows into table by using a backup table. But the table has a timestamp column so I can't insert values direct into this column. The column is not null, so I can't use NULL.... can you help me??

Os there a way to create while insert a default timestamp or is there a way to do my script??

```
insert into [dbo].[ZHG$Sales Order Price Scale_TEMP1] 
   ( timestamp
   ,[Order No_]
   , [Buy-from Vendor No_]
   , [Delivery Date (Price_Cond_)]
   , [Number of Storage Spaces]
   , [Price Scale Code]) 
       select null
            , [Order No_]
            ,[Buy-from Vendor No_]
            , [Delivery Date (Price_Cond_)]
            ,[Number of Storage Spaces]
            , [Price Scale Code] from [dbo].[ZHG$Sales Order Price Scale_TEMP]
```

Comment: Why do you want to provide a value for the `timestamp`? `timestamp` is a deprecated synonym for `rowversion`, which is a `binary(8)` value. It's meant to have its value controlled by the data engine as the value changes every time the row does. Just omit the `timestamp` column from your `INSERT` clause and SQL Server will automatically populate it with the `binary(8)` value.

Comment: `[ZHG$Sales Order Price Scale_TEMP1]` makes my brain hurt.

Comment: @AaronBertrand so do ALL of the column names.